# Sum currency with decimals [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I'm trying to sum such numbers like:

```
42,764.23
63,739.84
```

Simple select sum

```
SELECT sum(currency) as result from currency_table
```

The amount is `105`, but it should be `106,504.07`

If I add something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('', FORMAT(sum(currency),2)) as result from currency_table
```

The amount is `105.00`

Is there any way to get a proper result `106,504.07`?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the data type for `currency` is a string type and the comma in there confuses the engine while trying to do an implicit cast. Try to remove it.

```
SELECT sum(replace(currency, ',', '')) result
       FROM currency_table;
```

But you should really revise your design and use an appropriate numeric type for that column.

Comment: And the explanation for this: MySQL converts strings to numbers starting from the beginning and stopping at the end *or when it can’t continue*. So it thinks ‘42,764.23’ is just ‘42’. One of the fun things one has to learn if using it.

Comment: Is there any possible to sum the numbers in pure php?
$sum1 = 42,764.23
$sum2 = 63,739.84


$sum = ($sum1+$sum2)

Comment: @MarekSolskis: That should be addressed in a new question. This one is about SQL.